# Viewing event log via a web interface

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging, monitoring

I'd like to be able to view the event `log` for a series of `asp.net` websites running on IIS. Can I do this externally, for example, through a web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but there are two solutions I would recommend:

- Adiscon [EventLogger](http://www.eventreporter.com/en/) is a third-party product that will send your Windows EventLog to a SQL database. You can either send all events or create filters. Of course, once the events are in a SQL database, you can use any of the usual tools to create a web interface.
- You can use ASP.NET's [HealthMonitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx) configuration section to configure .NET to send all ASP.NET-related events directly to a SQL database. This covers exceptions, heartbeats, and a host of other event types. The [SqlWebEventProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.sqlwebeventprovider.aspx) is a cinch to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know if you can home-roll something or are you looking for an app you can get off the shelf?

I'm not a Windows guy, but I think Microsoft's MOM/SCOM solution will probably let you view the event log over a web UI - probably really heavy and expensive if that's all you need though.

A quick google found http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/Event_Logger.aspx which shows that you can get in if you want to roll your own... also an MS tool on [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en)

Sorry I can't be more help